# Error: could not find function "filterStream", any suggestion on why this error?

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to run the below code, that I found in the example of CRAN package **streamR** [link here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/streamR/streamR.pdf), but am getting an error when running it, can anyone tell me why this error and how can I resolve this. Thanks for your help.

```
## Not run:
## An example of an authenticated request using the ROAuth package,
## where consumerkey and consumer secret are fictitious.
## You can obtain your own at dev.twitter.com
library(ROAuth)
requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumerSecret <- "xxxyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzz1111111122222222"
my_oauth <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey, consumerSecret=consumerSecret, requestURL=requestURL, accessURL=accessURL, authURL=authURL)
my_oauth$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
filterStream( file="tweets_rstats.json",track="rstats", timeout=3600, oauth=my_oauth )
## capture 10 tweets mentioning the "Rstats" hashtag
filterStream( file.name="tweets_rstats.json", track="rstats", tweets=10, oauth=my_oauth )
## capture tweets published by Twitter's official account
filterStream( file.name="tweets_twitter.json", follow="783214", timeout=600, oauth=my_oauth )
## capture tweets sent from New York City in Spanish only, and saving as an object in memory
tweets <- filterStream( file.name="", language="es",locations=c(-74,40,-73,41), timeout=600, oauth=my_oauth )
## capture tweets mentioning the "rstats" hashtag or sent from New York City
filterStream( file="tweets_rstats.json", track="rstats",locations=c(-74,40,-73,41), timeout=600, oauth=my_oauth )
## End(Not run)
```

Comment: You need a package called streamR. Install streamR and then call filterStream

Answer (score 0):

May be the first filterStream, after "my_oauth$handshake"

```
filterStream( file="tweets_rstats.json",track="rstats", timeout=3600, oauth=my_oauth )
```

should be instead:

```
filterStream( file.name="tweets_rstats.json",track="rstats", timeout=3600, oauth=my_oauth )
```

Comment: Nope doesn't work, please check the link!

Comment: you load also another library `library(streamR)` (this is what a see at this [link](http://pablobarbera.com/blog/archives/1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you register a Twitter application on: [Twitter Apps](https://apps.twitter.com/)?
If so, did you set the callback URL on: http://127.0.0.1:1410?

What type of error did you get? I'm thinking about some problems with the authentication process, **filterStream** needs to pass the *my_oauth* to get authenticate and initiate the download.